# authCookie and relogin the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, session-timeout

**Scenario:**
I have a tricky situation where need to keep many modules happy [Google Analytics, etc, etc...]. Got a asp.net page in the project which initiates the request on the third party website (after clicking the Process button) and redirects the user to the third party website. Transaction is processed on their website and then the control is returned back to the current page on our site. You can relate this scenario with kind of Paypal processing too, but it's not paypal.

**Issue:**
If the session is time out, I want the user to be again authenticated when the control reaches our website after the processing is done on the third party website. So I am thinking of passing the authCookie information to the third party website and then when the control reaches our website back, I will have the authCookie information (imagine it is the scenario) and then want to log the user back in. Can I do that by just creating an authCookie again based on the username?

Comment: Not a good idea, I wouldn't pass that kind of info around... If you're paranoid, set a really long time out

Comment: This is interesting because you can't really say that the user is inactive, because he is still playing under the hood of your application. But I somewhat agree with Eric. If the user is away from your site, it's always a better idea to take them through official login page instead of auto-validating them. If that does not fit in business scenario, then put a long timeout.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the transaction processing system you are using. If you check the result of the transaction by calling their API, then the response usually have a user id or something that you can tie to user id. You can store the user name in the cookie, cookies are per domain or subdomain and it won't get sent to the transaction processing web site if it is in the different domain than yours, which is most likely the case. Get or derive the user name from the transaction result response, compare it to the one you obtain from your cookie. If they match up, sign in the user. Signing the user in just based on the cookie contents is risky in many respects. First of all anyone can set the cookie with any name in it to the browser. Second, if you are signing in a user just based on a cookie, you'll basically get never expiring session. This is not what you want. For added security you can check the transaction time from the transaction result response and refuse to sign in if it was too long ago.

Oh, and in you question you mention that you "need need to keep many modules happy" but you do not expand on as to what you mean by this. So I'm just simply ignoring this bit. Not sure what a happy module look like =)